# how to create a solution from a production directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I have a mvc project in production running on IIS.
I need make a little modification on visual studio 2015 but I cant build a new solution to edit the project.

how to build a new solution with the old files in production?

Comment: So you do not have the source code, but want to make a change  ?

Comment: I have a source code but no the solution file to the project on visual studio to recompile then

Comment: do you have  a project file, then create a new empty solution and add that project to it.